# How do I create a random property inside a randomly selected object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, if I have:

```
var weapon = [ "sword", "mace", "staff"];

var swordtype = [ "long", "short"];

var stafftype = [ "quarter", "magic"];
```

and my script randomly selects 'Sword' to display in my HTML p tag from the weapon variable.

How can I say that if my code randomly selects "Sword" from the weapon variable, it will also randomly select a "swordtype" to go with it? Making the output either "long sword" or "short sword"?

Comment: `weapon = { sword: ["long", "short"], mace: ["heavy", "light"], staff: ["quarter", "magic" }`? Or `[ { type: "sword", subtypes: ["long", "short"] }, {type: "staff", subtypes: ["quarter", "magic"] } ]`. Or some other, similar structure where each category of weapon has its variations directly associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to associate related data. So, your structure could be like this:

```js
// Use objects, not arrays to store key/value pairs
var weapons = {
  sword:["long","short", "broad"], 
  mace: ["standard", "long", "short"],
  staff: ["quarter", "magic", "wizard"],
  "nuclear missle": ["10 megaton", "20 megaton", "50 kiloton"],
  dagger: ["standard", "poison"]
};

// Function for selecting random weapon

function getRandomWeapon(){
  // Choose random weapon as an index from the weapons object:
  var weaponNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(weapons).length);
  
  // Get the property name that corresponds to that key number:
  var weapon = Object.keys(weapons)[weaponNum];

  // Choose random weapon type as an index from the random weapon selected above:
  var specificWeaponNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons[weapon].length);
  
  // Get the array value associated with that index
  var specifcWeapon = weapons[Object.keys(weapons)[weaponNum]][specificWeaponNum];
  return specifcWeapon + " " + weapon;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("weapon").textContent = getRandomWeapon();
});
```

```html
<div>You have a: <span id="weapon"></span></div>
<button>Get Weapon</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you SO much!